# show text If special user is logged

Tags: users, user-access

I want to check if special user id is logged in WordPress. i know we have a function name is_user_logged_in() but we can't change the id of user logged in, in this function.

I need a function like this:

`is_special_user_logged_in();`

and check it like this:

`if ( is_special_user_logged_in() ){
    echo 'special user is online';
}`

i can get the user id in one of bbpress file (loop-single-reply.php) by this code. get_post_field( 'post_author', bbp_get_reply_id() ); .Now i want to check if this user id logged in wordpress show a text like "this user is online". Note that i want to check it in another user logged in WordPress. it's mean if "USER A" logged in wordpress show a text to "USER B" that "USER A" is now logged in wordpress.

finally want to inform **USER A** about login status of **USER B**

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking for, *but*, if you want to target a specific user ID, just do something like:

```
// set special user id
$special_user_id = 5;

$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

if ( $special_user_id == $current_user_id ){
    echo 'special user is online';
}
```

You get the idea.

Comment: you posted 7 seconds before me, I will remove mine ;-)

Comment: @birgire No, keep yours. You're approach is slightly better to be honest.

Comment: Excuse me but it's not my question answer. i explain it again with more details. i can get the user id in one of bbpress file (loop-single-reply.php) by this code. `get_post_field( 'post_author', bbp_get_reply_id() );` .Now i want to check if this user id logged in wordpress show a text like "this user is online". Note that i want to check it in another user logged in WordPress. it's mean if "USER A" logged in wordpress show a text to "USER B" that "USER A" is now logged in wordpress. I hope you've noticed.

Comment: Do you mean: If $user_a login and $user_b is already logged in, then inform $user_a about it. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's right. i want to do this.

Comment: @ChristineCooper how can i do that?

Comment: This has already been resolved in the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559759/find-out-if-a-user-is-logged-into-wordpress-from-id

Comment: no it's not resolve. in that question we can only check if current user is login. but i want to inform "**USER A**" about login status of "**USER B**".

Comment: @saeedshabani please add all relevant information from your comments into your question, what you're describing in the comments is very different from the main question. Thanks

Comment: Ah right, I think I understand now. This has definitely been resolved already here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34429/how-to-check-if-a-user-not-current-user-is-logged-in -- please overview that properly. Just change the $user_to_check variable to the user ID of whom you wish to target.