# Can I use multisite functions in a single-site installation?

Tags: multisite, users

I'm trying to display some statistics of my Wordpress site in the footer. One of these statistics is the amount of users that are signed up.

There is a function called `count_users()` to display these statistics as show in the [Codex: count_users()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_users). But this function seems very server intensive, especially since it will be called on every WordPress page.

I started looking for less server intensive alternative and found one called `get_user_count()` [Codex: get_user_count()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_count). Unfortunately, this only seems to work on Multisite installations.

Is it possible to enable this and other Multisite functions for regular installations??

Comment: have you considered using `set_transient` and `get_transient` to cache the result for however long you like so that you are not calling `count_users` on every pageload?

Comment: You should probably have a look at this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/218140/17797)

Comment: added example :-)

Answer (score 1):

[get_transient](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_transient) / [set_transient](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_transient) example:

```
function my_get_user_count() {
    $usercount = get_transient('usercount');
    if (!$usercount) {
        $usercount = count_users();
        set_transient('usercount',$usercount,600); // ten mins
    }
    return $usercount;
}
```