# How to use a transient inside WP_User_Query

Tags: users, transient

*Source: [How to check if a user (not current user) is logged in?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34429/how-to-check-if-a-user-not-current-user-is-logged-in)*

I'm using a `transient` that's created when users login.

```
$logged_in_users = get_transient('users_online');
```

Now i'd like to create an extra function that lists all users that are currently online.

My code so far...

```
function wp_current_online_users(){

    $logged_in_users = get_transient('users_online');


    $args = array(
        'orderby'   =>  'display_name',
        'order'     =>  'ASC',
    );

    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

    // User Loop
    if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {

        foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {         
            $avatar = get_avatar( $user->ID, 40 );              
            echo '<span class="wp-user-'.$user->display_name.'">' . $avatar . ' </span>';               
        }

    } else {
        esc_html_e('There are currently no users logged in.', 'text-domain');
    }       

}
```

How to get implement the `transients` inside the `query` so that it will display online users only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that the referenced answer stores `users_online` as an array of timestamps indexed by user ID, you can use the [`include` argument for `WP_User_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Include_.26_Exclude_Parameters):

```
$args = array(
    'include' => array_keys( $logged_in_users ),
    // Other arguments
);
```